# Trouble looping through data in a javascript object

Tags: jquery, html, api

Having an issue with an object with true and false values. The object show up in the console like this.

Object {is_mem: false, has_mem: false, extendedtimeslot: false}

```
$.each(value, function () {
     console.log(value);
     $.each(this, function (name, value) {
       console.log("name-->> " + name + " value-->> " + value);
   });
});
```

I am just trying to log the values to the console at this point. Eventually I will assign to a variable. The loop iterates 3 times but I cannot aquire the values by key name.

Comment: What would you like the exact output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of objects:

```js
var objs = [{is_mem: false, has_mem: false, extendedtimeslot: false}];
$.each(objs, function () {
     $.each(this, function (name, value) {
       console.log("name-->> " + name + " value-->> " + value);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
name-->> is_mem value-->> false
name-->> has_mem value-->> false
name-->> extendedtimeslot value-->> false
```

See [the documentation for $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. That is the perfect answer.

Comment: ended up with this

Comment: var vesselsArray = value;
                                            $.each(vesselsArray, function (name, value) {
                                                console.log("name-->> " + name + " value-->> " + value);
                                            });
                                        
                                    }

Comment: @sixstring Glad it helped!

Comment: it was one of those things I was just staring at too long. Couldn't see the answer right in front of me :-)